# Add file name column to media library

Tags: media-library

I've migrated hosts for a WordPress site, and a lot of my images have the same title.

I am trying to pinpoint one media file by the file name, but file name is not a column listed in Media Library.

I don't want to have to wade through dozens of images with the same title trying to find the problem file name, so I can find the correct URL to this image.

**How can I add file name to the list of columns in Media Library?**

I can't search the media library by file name either.

Comment: You can also try my plugin, Media Library Assistant. It has a wide variety of features that help you find images, including the ability to add file name as a sortable column. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-assistant/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go, this code not only lists all filenames in Library but also allows you to sort them by name:

```
// Add the column
function filename_column( $cols ) {
    $cols["filename"] = "Filename";
    return $cols;
}

// Display filenames
function filename_value( $column_name, $id ) {
    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
    echo substr( strrchr( $meta['file'], '/' ), 1); 
    // Used a few PHP functions cause 'file' stores local url to file not filename
}

// Register the column as sortable & sort by name
function filename_column_sortable( $cols ) {
    $cols["filename"] = "name";
    return $cols;
}

// Hook actions to admin_init
function hook_new_media_columns() {
    add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', 'filename_column' );
    add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'filename_value', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'manage_upload_sortable_columns', 'filename_column_sortable' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hook_new_media_columns' );
```

Comment: what file do I add this code to?

Comment: functions.php of course! :)

Comment: Instead of `substr( strrchr( $meta['file'], '/' ), 1)` we can use `basename( $meta['file'] )`. The result is the same, but the code becomes more readable, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 1):

The code above for sorting with Filename works, if you change 2 things.

```
// Add the column
function filename_column( $cols ) {
    $cols["filename"] = "Filename";
    return $cols;
}

// Display filenames
function filename_value( $column_name, $id ) {
    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
    echo basename( $meta['file'] );  // CHANGE 1
    // Used a few PHP functions cause 'file' stores local url to file not filename
}

// Register the column as sortable & sort by name
function filename_column_sortable( $cols ) {
    $cols["filename"] = "Filename"; // CHANGE 2
    return $cols;
}

// Hook actions to admin_init
function hook_new_media_columns() {
    add_filter( 'manage_media_columns', 'filename_column' );
    add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'filename_value', 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'manage_upload_sortable_columns', 'filename_column_sortable' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hook_new_media_columns' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers the question directly but I was trying to get a "URL" column on the Media Library page (to avoid clicking the edit link every time...) and found [this code snippet](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/media-library-url-column-for-easy-copy-and-paste/) which does exactly that.

I played with it a little to get it to sort the URLs alphabetically and to strip the domain, to improve my workflow a bit more. Check it out:

```
<?php
function muc_column($cols) {
    $cols["media_url"] = "URL";
    return $cols;
}

function muc_value($column_name, $id) {
    if ($column_name == "media_url")

    $subject = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
    $grab = array("http://example.com", "http://another.example.com");
    $replaceWith = '';
    $path = str_replace($grab, $replaceWith, $subject);

    echo '<input
                type="text"
                width="100%"
                onclick="jQuery(this).select();"
                value="'.$path.'" />';
}

function muc_column_sortable($cols) {
    $cols["media_url"] = "name";
    return $cols;
}

add_filter('manage_media_columns', 'muc_column');
add_action('manage_media_custom_column', 'muc_value', 10, 2);
add_filter('manage_upload_sortable_columns', 'muc_column_sortable'); 
?>
```

I should mention it also presents the URL in an `<input>` that automatically selects the text when clicked, a nice feature for a quick copy and paste.