# add file name column to media library to sort by

Tags: media, library

I know that you have answered this but I am a self taught 50 something volunteer and I don't really understand where to place this.  If I go to editor (theme being used Asteria lite) and put the code into function php (at the very bottom) it shows as text on the page.  Is there anywhere specific that this must be posted. It is in the theme function file or should it be in the wordpress file somewhere? I really need help as I am trying to set this up for AWO as their adoption gallery

Comment: Where are you getting the code from? Can you post it here?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84030/add-file-name-column-to-media-library  I googled and found this, so this is what I am trying to add

Comment: Make sure that at the very top of your `functions.php` you have `<?php`, and at the very bottom a final `?>`. This ensures the code is executed as opposed to just displaying as text :)