# Add Filename Colum to Media Library

Tags: media-library

I know this has been asked before:
[Add file name column to media library](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84030/add-file-name-column-to-media-library/84039#84039?newreg=c4412952a3494fb1811460143d20dd67)
I tried the code. The Filename column was not polpulated.
Then I followed

> Instead of `substr( strrchr( $meta['file'], '/' ), 1)` we can use `basename( $meta['file'] )`. The result is the same, but the code becomes more readable,

Then the Filename column got populated but now the sort order is all over the place. Definitely not sorted.

Any pointers on how to fix this are very much appreciated.

Thanks!
cmyk

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

I just changed "name" to "Filename" on this function:

```
// Register the column as sortable & sort by name
function filename_column_sortable( $cols ) {
    $cols["filename"] = "Filename";
    return $cols;
}
```